# Django mixed data between executions

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I'm running Django over Apache with mod-wsgi in a Docker Container. When a request is processed by the view and executes a model method, everythins is ok, but when a second request is send, it's like it uses the same model instance from the past execution with the same variable values.

For example, when the first file is uploaded, it sets correctly it uploaded path, but when the second file is uploaded, it uses the last upladed path and add the new name to it.

This also happens with other methods.

```
class MediaFile(UploadedFile):
"""
Media File class. Accepts only files with ALLOWED_FORMATS. Store files in FILE_PATH.
"""
ALLOWED_FORMATS = ['BMP', 'PNG', 'TIFF', 'MP4', 'OGG', 'WEBM', '.AVI']
FILE_PATH = 'images/media/'

name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Name')
total_frames = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0, verbose_name='No of Frames')
upload = models.FileField(upload_to=FILE_PATH, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(ALLOWED_FORMATS)],
                          help_text='Formats permitted: %s' %
                                    (', '.join('.' + format.lower() for format in ALLOWED_FORMATS)),
                          verbose_name='File Uploaded'
                          )

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        self.name = hashlib.sha1((os.path.splitext(self.upload.name)[0] + str(time.time())).encode()).hexdigest()
        if self.create_folders(['FPGA', 'GPU', 'CPU']):
            self.upload.field.upload_to = os.path.join(self.upload.field.upload_to, self.name)
        else:
            return
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.send_file(['GPU', 'CPU'])
```

Comment: Well, yes, because you're changing the field attribute at class level. But you shouldn't do any of this, you should use a [callable `upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to).

Comment: Yes, I realize that now. Thanks!